# Swift Compare Set

Tags: facebook, swift, set

I try to check FB permissions, like this:

```
let permissions = ["user_friends", "public_profile"];
NSLog("Contains Permissions:%@", FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        .permissions);
    NSLog("Requested Permissions:%@", permissions);


    if(!FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions.contains(permissions)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

But it always returns false. Anyone an idea why ?

EDIT: Log output

```
Contains Permissions:{(
"user_friends",
"public_profile"
)}
2015-10-28 23:01:59.723: Requested Permissions:(
"user_friends",
"public_profile"
)
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your debugger and confirm that the permissions object actually does contain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains()` function you've used checks to see of any element of 'current Access Token' permissions is an array of `permissions`.  It is always `false` because the token permissions are strings, NOT arrays of strings.

If the two arrays need to have exactly the same elements, then the absolute simplest code would be:

```
let permissions = ["user_friends", "public_profile"];
NSLog("Contains Permissions:%@", FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        .permissions);
NSLog("Requested Permissions:%@", permissions);

tokenPermissions = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions as? [String]
return tokenPermissions != nil && tokenPermissions.sort().elementsEqual(permissions.sort())
```

You might first object to using `sort()`, perhaps as overkill, but otherwise you will be traversing the two lists of permissions multiple time so `sort()` ends up not being such a concern.

Another option is to iterate over the `tokenPermissions` and ensure that every one is in `permissions`.  Like such:

```
for tokenPermission in tokenPermissions {
  if !permissions.contains (tokenPermission) {
    return false
  }
}
return true
```

Or, if you got really ambitious and need to do a lot of sequence testing:

```
extension SequenceType {
  public func any (@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for elt in self {
      if predicate (elt) { return true }
    }
    return false
  }

  public func all (@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for elt in self {
      if !predicate (elt) { return false }
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

and then your code contains:

```
return tokenPermissions.all { permissions.contains ($0) }
```

And, finally, if the two arrays of permissions are actually sets of permissions then you can use

```
return Set(tokenPermissions).elementsEqual(Set(permissions))
```

So you've got a bunch of options.

Comment: Actually, this will not work as expected. The first solution with `elementsEqual` will for example only work when you get *exactly* the requested permissions. If you get more permissions than requested it will fail, although you got what you wanted. Otherwise I see no use in reinventing functions that are already implemented in the standard library.

Comment: Actually it works exactly as described: I said 'If the two arrays need to have exactly the same elements' to qualify the answer.  If, instead, he has a Set, then he can use my fourth snippet of code - and perhaps he modifies it if his permissions are actually subset relations.  No library functions have been duplicated - given the problem the OP described.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
if(!FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions.contains(permissions))
```

to:

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions.containsObject("user_friends") && FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions.containsObject("public_profile")
```

Solution for alot of set, see example code:

```
let permisssion = NSSet(array:["user_friends", "public_profile"])
    let test = NSSet(array: ["user_friends", "email","public_profile"])

    if permisssion.isSubsetOfSet(test as Set<NSObject>) {
        print("true")
    } else {
        print("false")
    }
```

Comment: So I get a set of functions to compare sets, such as isSubsetOf, isSupersetOf but I can't use them.... Instead I need to check each "statement" separately? Is this really the only solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is

```
let permissions = ["user_friends", "public_profile"]

let tokenPermissions = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions

NSLog("Contains Permissions:%@", tokenPermissions)
NSLog("Requested Permissions:%@", permissions)

guard let tokenPermissions = tokenPermissions as? Set<String> else {
    return false
}

return tokenPermissions.isSupersetOf(permissions)
```

For the `isSupersetOf(_:)` syntax see [Swift Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), you need to cast the untyped `NSSet` into a Swift `Set<String>` for the function to work.